Bash Script for Copying to Clipboard
My goal is to write an alias to copy the current command and its output to the clipboard, e.g.:
ls | myclip

This should result in the following being in the clipboard:
$ ls
Desktop Documents Downloads

Is this possible? So far, I tried:
myclip() {
    command="$@"
    output=$($@)
    echo -e "$command\n$output" | xclip -selection clipboard
}

This does not work, however.
Edit:
This seems to somewhat work, however, for me it does not handle line breaks in the output correctly:
copyclip(){
    cmd=$(history 1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* *//' | sed 's/|.*//');
    output=$(cat);
    echo "\$ "$cmd$'\n'$output | xclip -sel clipboard;
    echo $output;
}

If anybody knows how to fix the line break issue, that would be great!

You don't have an alias in the code you posted. BTW, read man xclip. It describes how stdin is placed into the clipboard.

It would be great if the command output would be copied to the clipboard as well as being displayed on the terminal.

No. I want this to be usable the way I described.

Do you want $  prepended to the text in the clipboard, or do you want the expansion of PS1?

I want the $ to be prepended.

Fixing the line breaks may be as simple as quoting "$output".  eg echo "$output" in the copyclip function.  If HISTTIMEFORMAT is set (and, HISTTIMEFORMAT should always be set, because a history file without timestamps is useless!) you will need to tweak the sed when filtering the output of history.

The function is fragile, but it should work if you just do printf "$ %s\n%s" "$cmd" "$output" | xclip ...

As far I can see, your question does not mention that the output should be shown in the terminal as well. Perhaps you can clarify this. However, a more tricky problem is that you said that you also want to have the command itself in the clipboard. Do you mean here "the command before expansion", or "after expansion"? Perhaps you could edit your question by adding the example: ls -A ~. What exactly would you like to see in the clipboard afterwards?

Working version:
copyclip(){
    cmd=$(history 1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* *//' | sed 's/|.*//');
    output=$(cat);
    echo "\$ "$cmd$'\n'"$output" | xclip -sel clipboard;
    echo "$output";
}


Define myclip function and run bind command :
myclip(){
    (( READLINE_POINT>0 )) || return 0
    local cmd="$READLINE_LINE"
    READLINE_LINE=''
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$cmd" "$($cmd)" | xclip -i -selection clipboard
}   

bind -x '"\e[15~":"myclip"'

Now type date followed by F5. The result will be in the clipboard.

You can Put this into .bashrc:
alias myclip="xsel -b"

and write this example command:
ls | myclip


Put the following alias into .bashrc:
alias myclip='xclip -i -selection clipboard'

Then open a new terminal and issue the following example command:
ls | myclip

That's all!

Thanks, but this does not copy the initial command to the clipboard.

(this answer should have been a comment, but I am not yet allowed to write them)
from my tests the issue seems to be that the script is acting as if  "$@"
contains the whole command before the pipe,
but, it does not work this way and performing this task in a clean and robust way can be tricky (see this post from more than 5 years ago)
the solution I have found is ugly and also I am afraid that it is far from being robust
the function
m() { (  echo "$( history 1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 26- | cut -d\| -f 1 )" ; cat  ) | xclip -i  ; }

(it works by echoing the command from history and then appending  stdin to stdout)
here is the test in bash (running from a ssh with putty)
/tmp $
/tmp $ m() { (  echo "$( history 1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 26- | cut -d\| -f 1 )" ; cat  ) | xclip -i  ; }
/tmp $
/tmp $ ls -1 foo
bar
baz
/tmp $
/tmp $
/tmp $ ls -1 foo |m
/tmp $ cat >/dev/null
this is the content of the clipboard when I paste it with shift-insert:
ls -1 foo
bar
baz
/tmp $


Thanks, but this does not work for me. I get:
$ m() { (  echo "$( history 1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 26- | cut -d| -f 1 )" ; cat  ) | xclip -i  ; }
$ ls | m
Clipboard: m() { (  echo "$( history 1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 26- | cut -d| -f 1 )" ; cat  ) | xclip -i  ; }

you are correct: in order for my solution also to work from terminal to Text Editor or other X11 apps  I  needed to specify the xclip flags as in your original script i.e.:
  `m() { (  echo "$( history 1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 26- | cut -d\| -f 1 )" ; cat  ) | xclip -selection clipboard ; }`


Also does not work. It is missing the command.

@beautifulsouper
could you please provide additional info on your environment (unix/linux distro, shell version, terminal, GUI app in which pasting the copied text) ?

clipsmth() { (echo "\$ $@"; $@;) | xclip -sel clipboard; }
and call it like clipsmth ls -l if that you wanted
